# UWP: Issues with setting ImageSource when no Internet is available

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a scenario where I have UI which has a dropdown and an image. This UI shows the first item(Item A) in the dropdown selected which shows Image A on the UI. When this UI shows up first the internet is disconnected. I still see Image A. Now I try to select another item from the dropdown Item B and this time I don't see Image B.

This is how I set the Image Source

UI:

```
<Image source= "{x:bind Viewmodel.SampleImage}, mode=OneWay">
</Image>
```

Backend :

```
private ImageSource sampleImage;
public ImageSource SampleImage
{
   get => this.sampleImage;
   set => this.SetProperty(ref this.sampleImage, value);
 }

public void Initialize()
{
   // Everytime I change my selection from the dropdown this function is triggered which tries to set the value of Image displayed in the UI
    BitmapImage fallbackImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("https://randomImage"));
    this.SampleImage = fallbackImage;
 }
```

I need help in understanding why the second image Image B does not show up when the internet is disconnected here.And how do I handle this case when the internet is disconnected and I need to still display the image if I don't have local fallback images.

Comment: According to the current situation, Image B is not visible at the beginning, so Image B is not rendered. Could you please introduce the control for the images collection and provide a reproducible example.

Comment: How are you supposed to download and display "https://randomImage" if you're not connected to the internet...? Or what exactly is your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you share, the `Initialize` method will only be triggered when the dropdown selection is changed, so the image is actually downloaded only when the item is selected.

When you disconnect from the internet, the download action will fail. The `image B` will not be show because the image is not downloaded. The reason why `image A` still should is that the **BitmapImage** will cache the image it uses before.